# What is the name of this about 10cm high, grey, "flat hat" fungus?

Tags: species-identification, mycology

I found this fungus on Corsica (France). Can you please help me to identify it?

[image]

Comment: In fungi, you should always look at the underside of the hat, which gives big clues to group/species determination.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the **dark lamellae** and the **ring** around the foot, I would bet on something in the Agaricus genus. The French Wikipedia gives quite some details about common species in this genus: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agaric

Answer (score 1):

Try looking up Chlorophyllum  brunneum or commonly called a shaggy parasol.
http://www.mykoweb.com/CAF/species/Chlorophyllum_brunneum.html
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I think this goes in the right direction. However, it could also be https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Chlorophyllum_molybdites or any other Chlorophyllum, I guess?

Comment: Most Lepiota don't have such dark lamellae.

Comment: Besides the lamellae colour, the foot seems too wide in proportion to the hat for a Lepiota, in my opinion.